# How to redirect to app after user logged-in when clicked on share button

Tags: facebook, sdk

I am using javascript SDK to implement feed functionality. Here is my problem, if user is not logged-in and clicked on share button facebook asking log-in credentials and successfully logged in redirecting to facebook home page instead of my app.

How do we give redirect url in FB.ui method so that it will redirect to my APP.

Here is my code

```
FB.ui( {
    method : 'feed',
    name : feedName,
    link : feedLink,
    picture : feedImg,
    caption : feedCaption,
    description : feedDescription,
    message : feedMessage
});
```

Can you please help me how to resolve this issue using FB.ui method.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `callback` for [`FB.ui`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) method:

```
FB.ui({
  method : 'feed',
  name : feedName,
  link : feedLink,
  picture : feedImg,
  caption : feedCaption,
  description : feedDescription,
  message : feedMessage
}, function(response){
  if (response && response.post_id) {
    alert('Post was published.');
  } else {
    alert('Post was not published.');
  }
});
```

You can also specify `redirect_uri` in options, but generally `FB.ui` provide it automatically.

If user redirected not to your application the problem probably with initialization of Facebook JS-SDK.

You can also use `FB.login` prior to calling to `FB.ui`

Comment: Thank you But I need after user log-in in the facebook redirect to my app. JS-SDK initialization is correct because everything working for me. Getting photos from albums and Page information like everything working, What should I check whether Facebook JS-SDK initialized properly or not.

Comment: Do you running this code on a domain listed in your application settings? BTW, you're using `message` property of feed dialog which is deprecated and no longer works for half of the year...

Comment: Thank you for info I will remove message property. Yes I am running this code same domain which is listed in the application setting.  Even I used redirect_uri property but no luck.